Prevent zoom out beyond north and south bounds of map
I'm looking for a way to prevent my Leaflet JS map from displaying areas beyond the north and south poles. My objective is to keep the map's view within the confines of the Earth's surface.
Is there a standard way to do this?
I've set maxBounds which works great for panning but not for zoom:
maxBounds: [
  [-85, -180],
  [85, 180],
],


Ah, I've got this working.  Using this solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/352976/241615
I had tried this before but had forgotten to take into account that I am using tiles that are 512px instead of 256px 
    let width = jQuery("#mainMap").width();
    let height = jQuery("#mainMap").height();
    let minZoom = Math.ceil(Math.log2(Math.max(width, height) / 512));
    map.options.minZoom = minZoom;

